# Drupal 7 Multilingual Site Search

Tags: 7, hooks, search, i18n-l10n

I have a drupal multilingual site (English and Arabic) . Arabic page site search gives me an extra value "English" in search result. I am using default drupal site search.
 [image]

What it actually means? How can i remove this?

Comment: I think this question is a case of "not enough data". If you are directed to English version of a node, that's it - indication that a result is in different language than you expect. Are you using built-in search or contrib module? Are nodes independent or marked as translations of another?

Answer (score 1):

That is because of language switcher enabled.  Go the particular content type page, edit and in publishing options CHECK the check box Hide content translation links.  [image]